# How can I simulate HTTP requests in different encodings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, encoding, utf-8

I run a Ruby on Rails application and since the site is becoming increasingly popular internationally, I started having errors related to encoding, eg:

Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xE8" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

I'm trying to find an HTTP request simulator that supports various encodings to reproduce the errors, but I'm not having much luck.

Does anyone know how to simulate or test HTTP requests with non UTF8 parameters / path infos?

Answer (score 0):

An encoding is just how your represent your text into bytes. As long as you encode/decode the text using the same encoding, you should be fine. If you encode/decode it using different encodings, it'll interpret the byte sequences differently and result in errors.

Normally, you are in control of the encodings used and the webserver can handle basic conversions.
Browser <--encoding--> server <--encoding--> files

There is normally no need to "find an HTTP request simulator that supports various encodings" since you usually define which one is used on server side, or the webserver handles the conversion.

If there is some strange client using some strange encoding that can't be recognized, I'd say it's either a serious issue in your webserver, your configuration or something similar. ...or in the files themeselves that are not encoded in the same format you use to read them.

...lastly, I believe almost any HTTP client supports many encodings for the body.

EDIT:

Since you mention URLs:

URLs must be encoded using plain old ASCII. Even if you use fancy UTF8 characters, the browser will translate them underneath.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Using a strange encodings for URLs and invalid characters is a client error and should be fixed client side IMHO.